# Paypal invoice status stays on "DRAFT"

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

i have got a problem recently trying to make a paypal invoice. well, check this code here.

```
paypal.invoice.create({
        merchant_info: {
            email: "EMAIL",
            first_name: "FIRST_NAME",
            last_name: "LAST_NAME",
            business_name: "NAME",
            phone: {
                country_code: "CODE",
                national_number: "NUMBER"
            },
            address: {
                line1: "STREET",
                city: "Riyadh",
                state: "Riyadh Province",
                postal_code: "0000",
                country_code: "SA"
            }
        },
        status: "UNPAID",
        billing_info: [{
            "email": "example@example.com"
        }],
        items: [],
        note: `Thank You For Buying`
    })
```

Ok, i got the invoice made and everything, but the status is "DRAFT", can someone explain please?
btw i want the status to be "UNPAID"

Answer (score 0):

[PayPal-Node-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK) is deprecated, so don't use that. There is no supported SDK for the invoicing API; use direct API calls.

(Some of the HTTP call code in the newer [Checkout-NodeJS-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NodeJS-SDK) could possibly be useful to you as a template)

Regarding the [v2 invoicing API itself](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/invoicing/integrate/), invoices start in a DRAFT state on creation. There is an additional API call to send them, documented on that page.